# Selecting and deselecting drawn objects on canvas and moving to mouse X and Y

Tags: javascript, canvas, constructor, prototype

The attached code shows how to select (on click) a drawn object on canvas and then the object is moved with a double click to click position or deselected with a double click prior to/ post-movement.

I have tried for days but could not work out how to apply this function to all objects in a class or an array via looping (via class constructor + prototyping). I would like to be able to select or deselect any object on screen.

Help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
 }
 body {
  margin: 0px;
 }     
</style>

</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input id="click1" type ="button" value="x" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 650px; position: absolute;"></input>
<input id="click2" type ="button" value="y" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 750px; position: absolute;"></input>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  let strokeColor;
  let color;
  let mouse_x;
  let mouse_y;
  let x;
  let y;
  let w;
  let h;
  let selected = false;
  x = 50;
  y = 50;
  w = 50;
  h = 50;
  color="green";
  strokeColor = "green";
    
  document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("mousemove",go);
  
  document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("mouseup",mouseUp);
  
  document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("dblclick",dblClick);
  
  document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener("dblclick",move);
  
  function move(){
   
   if(selected == true){
   x = mouse_x;
   y = mouse_y;
   
   }
  }
  
  function mouseUp(){
   
   if(mouse_x > x && mouse_x < x+w && mouse_y > y && mouse_y < y+w){
   strokeColor = "black";
   selected = true;
   console.log(selected);
   }
   
  }
   
  function dblClick(){
   
   if(mouse_x > x && mouse_x < x+w && mouse_y > y && mouse_y < y+w){
   color = "green";
   strokeColor = color;
   selected = false;
   console.log(selected);
   }
  } 
  
  function go(e){
   
   mouse_x = e.clientX;
   mouse_y = e.clientY;
   document.getElementById('click1').value = mouse_x;
   document.getElementById('click2').value = mouse_y;
   
  }  

  function draw(){
   context.strokeStyle = strokeColor;;
   context.fillStyle = color;
   context.beginPath();
   context.lineWidth = 3;
   context.rect(x,y,w,h);
   context.fill();
   context.stroke();   
  }
    
  function animate(){
   
   context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
   context.save();
   draw();
   context.restore();
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      
  }
   
  animate();
    
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy to do, let's first talk about the logic that we need.

1. Have a list of items that we can draw.
2. Make those items have their own state.
3. Check if when we click we hit an item or not.
4. Move or toggle the selected item.
5. Handle Clear & Draw of the canvas.

Made this simple fiddle just to show you the idea behind it,

```js
let context = $("canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
let elements = [
 new element(20, 20, 20, 20, "green"),
 new element(45, 30, 30, 30, "red"),
 new element(80, 40, 50, 50, "blue"),
];
let mousePosition = {
 x: 0,
 y: 0,
};
let selected;

function element(x, y, height, width, color) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.height = height;
 this.width = width;
 this.color = color;
 this.selected = false;

 this.draw = function(context) {
  context.strokeStyle = (this.selected ? "black" : "white");
  context.fillStyle = this.color;
  context.beginPath();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.rect(this.x, this.y, this.height, this.width);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
 }
 
 this.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
 }
}

//Select Function
function get_select(x, y) {
 let found;

 $.each(elements, (i, element) => {
  if(x > element.x
  && x < element.x + element.width
  && y > element.y
  && y < element.y + element.height) {
   found = element;
  }
 });
 return (found);
}

// Handle selection & Movement.
$("canvas").click(function() {
 let found = get_select(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);

 Clear();
 // Toggle Selection
 if (found && !selected) {
  found.selected = true;
  selected = found;
 } else if (found === selected) {
  found.selected = false;
  selected = null;
 }

 // Move
 if (!found && selected) {
  selected.move(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
 }
 Draw();
});

// Record mouse position.
$("canvas").mousemove((event) => {
 mousePosition.x = event.pageX;
 mousePosition.y = event.pageY;
});

//Draw ALL elements.
function Draw() {
 $.each(elements, (i, element) => {
  element.draw(context);
 });
}

function Clear() {
 context.clearRect(0, 0, $("canvas")[0].width, $("canvas")[0].height);
}

// Start.
$(document).ready(() => {
 Draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <body>
  <canvas></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Hope it helps you out!**

Comment: Thank you, Leo. What did you use alongside pure Javascript ? I see some library script. I've not touched on libraries yet. In my code, I also wanted to implement selection (or deselection) and movement of as many objects as I wanted to the same click position. While some code is very clear to me - other parts will take me sometime to digest. I like the logic of selecting and finding. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @AlexH please do not edit someone else's answer to post your improvement for the code. Edit the post only if you've found the typo or syntax errors. Post a self-answer with the adopted code with a proper link to the adopted code.

Comment: @AlexH just used the basic selector with Jquery, you should be able to learn and use it really fast, that's why i used, to make you learn the basics of jquery, this kind of stuff is usually done with jquery selectors, it will make your life easier than pure javascript. https://api.jquery.com/, Btw i did answer your question, and made you a testable solution, i would hope to get selected as the right answer for the post.